# Wherein Aithreya Brahmana of Rig Veda has the word "Telugu"?

Tags: scripture, rig-veda

The Etymology of **Telugu** is believed to be derived from word "**TRILINGA**" or [Trilinga Kshetras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinga_Kshetras). Those three Shiva Temples are [Kaleswaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleshwaram), [Bhimeswarama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draksharama)  and [Srisailam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srisailam).

With time *Trilinga* became *Tenugu* and *Tenugu* became *Telugu.* These three Shiva Temples are present in three regions (Kosta Andhra, Telangana and Rayalaseema) of Telugu land. [Telangana Region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telangana) which is located approximately amid these three Shiva Temples is named after *Trilinga Desa*. (Trilinga- Telugu- Telangana).

But some people believe Telugu is still older language and it is mentioned in [Aithreya Brahmana of Rigveda](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu). So, wherein Aithreya Brahmana of Rigveda, "**Telugu**" is mentioned?

Comment: the article says "Rigveda (literature dates to 7000 years before CE) ".  that kind of dents its credibility, doesn't it?

Comment: It is said (I’m not sure where) in the days of yore, the region was referred to as the Andhra kingdom, which does find mention in the Aitareya Brahmana. However in this Kaliyuga, after many years, the region was divided into smaller principalities. It was at this time that either Devi or Mahadeva (not sure who) appeared and caused the principalities between the 3 Lingams to be united as Trilinga Desha. There would therefore be no mention of Trilinga Desha in the Aitareya Brahmana. Trilinga and Andhra are not synonymous. Andhra is wider whereas Trilinga is only between these 3 Lingams.

Answer (score 3):

The Andhras was mentioned in [Aitareya Brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft_djvu.txt), which is as follows:

> This Risi Visvamitra had a hundred sons, fifty of them were older
> than Madhuchhandtls, and fifty were younger than he. The older ones
> were not pleased with (the installation of SunaWepa to the primogeni-
> ture).
>
> VisvAmitra then pronounced against  them the curse,
>
> " You shall have the lowest castes for your descendants."
>
> Therefore are many of the most degraded classes of men, the rabble for
> the most part, such as the **Andhras**, Pwidras, Saharas, Paltndas, and
> Miitibas, descendants of  Visvamitra.
>
> But Madhuchhandas, with the fifty younger sons, said,  " What our
> father approves of, by that we abide ; we all accord to thee
> (^unahsepa) the first rank, and we will come after thee ! "
> Vijivtlmitra,  (leligated 'at this answer) then praised these sons
> with the following  verses :
>
> " Ye my sons will have abundance of cattle and children, for you  have
> made me rich in children by consenting to my wish."

---

The same Andhras might have lived in trIlinga desa, as stated in the question, and later the language got the name Telugu.