# Does hindu scripture discuss south india, dravida desa and languages?

Tags: puranas, sanskrit

Sanskrit shows no affinity to dravidian, unlike european languges even though dravidian being in its vicinity, is there any purana which discusses the differences between north-south india, or its totally alien languages in contrast to sanskrit? How did south indian languges came to be.

Comment: I think is already asked once and deleted because it was off-topic. This is a language question and nothing to do with religion.

Comment: Puranas do describe places like Srisailam, Kanchi, Venkatachala (Varaha kshetra and Tirumala), Rameswaram and many other places, Andhra, Dravida are mentioned at several places. Dravida = dravya+vida which itself is sanskrit. Your question has many assumptions.

Comment: See [What Mleccha languages are used in the Vedas according to Purva Mimamsa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15121/3500) and [Wherein Aithreya Brahmana of Rig Veda has the word “Telugu”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11111/3500)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "does **hindu scripture** discuss"

Comment: @Anisha I know. I am sure about it. [Same question was asked](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28113/5212). It was "What do Hindu scriptures say about Dravidians and Dravidian languages" and it was off-topic and now it "Does Hindu scriptures discuss". It is a language question and a history question which is off-topic for the site. It is more apt for [history]. I can ask about every language putting What do HIndu scriptures say in the beginning.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I beg to differ the question is asked based on a scriptural and Vedic/post-vedic perspective and it isn't opinion-based either, so this is very on-topic. Otherwise, questions regarding other religions from a Hindu perspective may also be considered "off-topic" This question while may fit a historical and linguistical site, is being answered based on scripture or Vedic theological sources.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a partial answer.

The Dravida word itself is a Sanskrit word as said by The Destroyer.

In Manu Smriti Dravida is simply mentioned as the name of a Vratya caste who used to be originally Kshatriyas but due to non-performance of Samskaras and sacred rites attained the Vratya status.

> 10.21. But from a Vratya (of the) Brahmana (caste) spring the wicked Bhriggakantaka, the Avantya, the Vatadhana, the Pushpadha, and the
>   Saikha.
>
> 10.22. **From a Vratya (of the) Kshatriya (caste)**, the Ghalla, the Malla, the Likkhivi, the Nata, the Karana, the Khasa, and **the
>   Dravida**

To understand what this term Vratya means see the following verse from the same text:

> 10.20. Those (sons) whom the twice-born beget on wives of equal caste, but who, not fulfilling their sacred duties, are excluded from the
>   Savitri, one must designate by the appellation Vratyas.

Regarding mentions of Dravida Desha, probably such mentions are found in Puranas like Bhagavata Purana (unable to find the exact verse now).

Here is a reference from the [Bhavishya Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=22):

> After the demise of Vikramaditya of the Golden Age in Bharat, there
>   were as many as eighteen Kingdoms named Indraprastha, Panchaala,
>   Kurukshetra, Kampila, Antarvedi, Vraja, Ajmer, Marudhanva (Mawaad),
>   Gurjara ( Gujarat), Maharashtra, Dravida (Tamilnadu), Kalinga
>   (Orissa), Avanti (Ujjain), Udupa (Andhra), Banga, Gauda, Magadha and
>   Kaushalya.

Comment: Does any hindu scripture talk about dravidian lamguages, which are different then even prakrits.

Comment: I am not aware whether Hindu scriptures do that or not.. but dravida desha probably is mentioned. @Anisha

Comment: okay, so does hindu scripture mention language families? Christians have the tower of babel myth, is there any myth mentioning how difference in languages came to be?

Comment: You can also say about places mentioned in Skanda Purana. Arunachala (Arunachala mahatmyam)(Tiruvannamalai), Kanchi (Place of Kamakshi), Rameswaram (setu mahatmyam), Venkatachala Mahatmyam (Varaha Kshetra and Tirumala Venkateswara)

Comment: "Does any hindu scripture talk about dravidian lamguages, which are different then even prakrits. – Anisha" No Hindu scriptures generally won't talk about languages. It is languages which talk about Hinduism. No language is superior to other languages. There are many who met the highest positions with god in different language other than Sanskrit(the language you mentioned).  Language is tool to meet god. There are other animals(not humans) who reached highest position in Hinduism. Do they know Sanskrit?

Comment: But is OP looking for such info? Not sure. Probably he/she already knows about the greatness of those sacred places? @TheDestroyer

Comment: @Anisha I will have a look into Bhavisya Purana to see if i can find more info regarding the language part.

Answer (score 0):

**South India**

[sahyadri khanda uttarardha ch. 1 of skanda purana](https://archive.org/details/Sahyadri-Khanda/page/n314/mode/1up) discusses south india (south of vindhyas) :

[image]
[image]

**Dravida language**

According to agni puraNa Chapter 337, languages are of two types - sanskrita and prakrita:

> 8. Saṃskṛta (laṅguage) is for the gods and others. There are three varieties of Prākṛta for men.

This nAtyashAstra Chapter XVIII describes prakrita language which includes dravida language:

> 3. In connexion with the dramatic representation, it (the Prakrit recitation) is of three[5] kinds, viz, that with the same words [as in
>    Sanskrit] (samāna-śabda), that with corrupt (vibhraṣṭa) words and that
>    with words of indigenous origin (deśī).

> 47. The Seven [major] dialects (bhāṣā) are as follows: Māgadhī, Āvantī [Avantijā], Prācyā, Śaurasenī (Śūrasenī), Ardhamāgadhī, Bāhlīkā, **Dākṣiṇātyā**.[46]

> 48. In the dramatic composition there are, besides, many less important dialects (vibhāṣā)[47] such as the speeches of the Śakāra, Ābhīras, Caṇḍālas, Śabaras, **Dramiḍas**,[48] Oḍras, and the lowly speech of the foresters.