# The formation of Parashurama Kshetra

Tags: puranas, parashurama

There is a popular belief in the western part of India that the territory was reclaimed by Parashurama from Varuna, leading to its popular designation as Parashurama Kshetra or Tulu Nadu. Additionally, Parashurama is credited with the creation of the Tulu language.

According to this belief, after Parasurama killed all the Kshatriyas in the world and donated the land to Sage Kashyapa. He went on to Sahyadri to start a meditation on Lord Shiva. Shiva then instructed him to meditate in what was then known as Kadalivana, which would later become Kadri (currently in the state of Karnataka). However, upon Parashurama's arrival at Kadalivana, he found it submerged by the ocean. So, Parashurama went to the Varuna and asked him to withdraw the ocean from that particular area. When Varuna declined, Parashurama, in a fit of anger, hurled his axe. Fearing his wrath, Varuna withdrew the ocean from the vicinity where the axe had landed, resulting in the reclamation of the land that now constitutes a portion of the west coast of India.

My question is, does the formation of the West Coast as Parashurama Kshetra have any reference in Purana or is it folklore?

Answer (score 4):

The Brahmanda Purana discusses the story of how Parasurama reclaimed the land from Varuna.

In [Chapter 57 of Upodghāta-pāda](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362914.html) of Brahmanda Purana. The sages who had their homes in Gokarna visited Parashurama at Mahendra Parvatha, requesting him to reclaim the Holy Kshetra of Gokarna which was caused to fall into the water by the sons of Sagara when they were digging up the Earth.

> *12. After bowing down to Rāma, those sages said thus:—“O excellent sage, understand that we are the sages who had our homes in
> **Gokarṇa**.*
>
> *13. That great holy place along with the sacred ponds etc. was caused to fall into the waters of the ocean by the sons of Sagara who were
> digging up Earth for some other reason.*
>
> *14. Undoubtedly, we desire and expect from you to regain that holy spot that sanctifies everyone, after causing the waters of the ocean
> to recede.*
>
> *17. It behoves you, O leading Brāhmaṇa, to grant that excellent holy spot now, after causing the waters of the ocean to recede, by your own
> prowess”.*
>
> *25-26. On being earnestly requested by the sages thus, the intelligent scion of the family of Bhṛgu acceded to it, for the sake
> of Dharma only in his view. Along with them, the excellent sage
> proceeded towards the **South-Western direction**, O king, with a
> desire to see the lord of rivers (Varuṇa).*
>
> *27. The leading scion of the family of Bhṛgu, the noble-minded sage Rāma descended from **Sahya, the excellent mountain** and reached the
> **western shore of the lord of rivers**.*

Convinced by the sage's request, Parashurama descends from Mahendra Parvatha and reaches the West Coast. Parashurama requests Varuna to return the land.  But Varuna doesn't respond to Parashurama's plea. Believing that Varuṇa had ignored his request. This infuriated Parasurama, who attempted to shoot his arrow to dry up the ocean. Afraid of this outcome, Varuna surrendered to Parashurama and granted his request. Then Parashurama (mentally) decided on the boundary. He whirled his Sruvā (the sacrificial ladle) with great speed and hurled it into the sea. went 200 Yojanas in the direction of the northwest and fell. (Ref : [Upodghāta-pāda ch 58](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362915.html))

> *1. On seeing Varuṇa who said this and fell on the ground at his feet, the intelligent leading member of the family of Bhṛgu, withdrew the
> missile.*
>
> *2. After withdrawing the missile, Rāma looked at Varuṇa standing in front of him. Anger having subsided, he said to him smilingly.*
>
> *3. “These leading sages who had their homes in Gokarṇa had come to me before, O lord of rivers, while I was staying on the mountain
> Mahendra.*
>
> *4. The holy spot Gokarṇa inhabited by the sages was caused to fail down into your waters formerly, by the sons of Sagara who were digging
> the Earth.*
>
> *5. After having approached me, those sages, the residents of that holy place have rushed down here to regain once again that holy spot
> which is very dear to Śiva.*
>
> *14. Then he mentally decided the boundary. Wishing to point it out, O king, he took up his Sruvā (the sacrificial ladle). The intelligent
> sage was desirous of **throwing it in the ocean**.*
>
> *15-18. After making him (Rāma) delighted in his mind and devoid of anger towards himself (i.e. Varuṇa), the lord of rivers disappeared.
> When he had gone, Rāma stood facing the north. **He whirled his Sruvā
> with great speed and hurled it into the briny sea**. When it was
> hurled into the ocean, the Sruvā went two hundred Yojanas in the
> direction of the north-west, O king, and fell down. That place is the
> holy spot named Śūrpāraka. It is conducive to rid oneself of all sins.
> It is on the shore of the lord of rivers and well-known in the three
> worlds. The Sruvā (sacrificial ladle) slipping down from Rāma’s hands
> fell, O great king between that holy spot (and the shore of the
> ocean), thereby indicating Rāma’s exploit.*
>
> *19-22. The place, O king, where the ground created by Rāma was established is the holy place Śūrpāraka, glorious and renowned in all
> the worlds. The ocean withdrew its waters so far. After granting the
> Earth to Rāma, O king, he stood aside. Rāma (the leading member of
> Bhṛgu’s family) who never transgressed the bounds of decency made him
> stand by this agreement accepted by himself (i.e. Varuṇa), knowing
> that it is the eastern  boundary on the Earth, the ocean yielded the
> ground.*
>
> *23-25. All the gods were surprised to see the exploit of Rāma. When the water of the ocean receded there on the Sahya mountain, there were
> here and there (at some places) some markings of boundaries of towns
> and villages as before (their submerging in the sea). These he
> observed there by chance, due to their lower level. Thereafter, the
> most excellent member of the family of Bhṛgu, lovingly gave their
> respective places as desired by them to the sages of purified souls.*

Comment: @ekAnitka, edited your answers for better readability.

Comment: This account from the Purana is quite different from what is being said as part of the Tulu Nadu history. Do have any idea about the reference to the Tulu language

Comment: Ok, this is the closest I found from purana so far. Reg tulu language, puranaas mention a a southern language as part of prakrit language but don't get into specific like tulu etc. Sahyadri khanda is another text which might have above story but it's eng translation is not available, sanskrit is here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53700/21696

Comment: there are two versions of Skanda Purana. The popular one is covering only seven khadas - Maheśvara, Vaiṣṇava, Brahma, Kāśī, Āvantya, Nāgara and Prabhāsa. Even G. V. Tagare's work also covers only above 7 khandas. Some people even considered Sahyadri Khanda and other Khandas (Manasa, Himavat, Patala, Ayodhya, Bhima, Mathura Khandas) of Skanda Purana to be interpolation. Check this link - https://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/1327294-information-on-sahyadri-kanda-in-skanda-purana/. Anyways thanks for the resource.